# How can I do time lapse photography while shooting directly to a desktop?

Tags: software, timelapse, tethering

I am looking to shoot a 24 hour timelapse, with a 1 minute interval between images. I would be aiming to do this directly onto my desktop computer, is there software or a script that would allow for this meaning a hands off approach to the photography once it gets going and I could leave it alone without having to press a button or monitor it.

I personally have a Canon 400d (not the most advanced/up to date but it can be tethered) but also have access to a Canon 60d with a better lens so would be inclined towards using that. The question was more what available software allows for tethered timelapse shooting.

Comment: what camera and model  ?  look at your user manual to see if it supports tethering.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what camera you have. Most DSLRs can be tethered, as well as many mid-range and high-end bridge camera.Assuming you have a camera that supports tether control, you will need several things for a 24-hour timelapse:

1. **Tether connection**: Just about any camera today that supports tethering can be connected to a PC with a USB cable (sometimes it's a proprietary connector at the camera's end of the cable, but it's still USB). Some cameras today can be controlled over a wifi connection. Your camera probably came with a PC USB cable.
2. **Tethering software**: There are lots of choices for PC (and even iOS and Android) software to control your camera. Not all software that is called "tether" software can control the camera's exposure and shutter, but many can. [Tether Tools maintains an excellent list of tethered control software](https://www.tethertools.com/plugging-in/software/). Again, without knowing what camera you have, or operating system your desktop computer is running, I can't reduce the list of software any better than that.
3. **Power**: You might run out of battery power long before your 24-hour timelapse is complete. To prevent that, you will want an AC power adapter for your camera. Most, but not all, DSLRs can be powered by a special adapter. Most of those that can utilize a special adapter that fits into the battery compartment, with a wire hanging out to connect to a switching DC power supply connected to the mains power. If you have a Nikon camera, [Nikon's list of AC power supply compatibility](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/322/~/battery,-charger-and-ac-adapter-compatibility) will tell you if you can power the camera from mains power, and what adapter(s) you need to do it. I have not been able to find a similar list for Canon cameras. I haven't searched for other brands.

Comment: For Canon AC Power Supplies, I find that most camera store websites can generate a list or show you which one from you informing what camera you are using. (going based on Canadian websites)

Comment: I'm not sure Canon has ever published a single list of every camera model and the appropriate AC power adapter. They tend to create lists of all of the compatible accessories they make for each camera model. So to find an adapter for a specific model one would find it among the replacement eyecups, diopter adapters, remote shutter releases, etc. on the list of accessories for that particular model.

Comment: Beyond the XX00D/Rebel line, there are only two primary battery groups within the Canon EOS model line. The 1D X and 1D X Mark II (and many earlier 1-series models) use the LP-E4/LP-E4N/LP-E19 series that have different capacities but are all the same size and backwards/forwards compatible with each other and all use the same AC adapter. The 5D Mark II/III, 7D, 7D Mark II, 6D, 5Ds, 5Ds R, 60D, 70D, and 80D all use the LP-E6/LP-E6N series. These are also the same battery with slightly different capacities that are backwards/forwards compatible and all use the same AC power adapter.

Comment: The last x0D series camera released by Canon that does not use a variant of the LP-E6 battery was the 50D released in 2008. The last 1-series camera to not use a variant of the LP-E4/LP-E19 battery is the 1D Mark II N released in 2005. All of the other xD series camera use the LP-E6 series of batteries.

Comment: Many earlier Canon model lines used the BP-511/BP-511A/BP-512/BP-514 batteries that were, again, all the same size and voltage and only varied based on their recharge capacity. Cameras using any of those batteries would share the same AC power adapter. Models that used this series of batteries included the D30, D60, 10D, 20D, 30D, 40D, 50D, 5D, and the original Rebel/300D.

Comment: The NP-E3 powered the early 1-series models: 1D, 1Ds, 1D Mark II, 1D Mark II N, 1Ds Mark II.

Comment: @MichaelClark wow, that is a comprehensive rundown! Maybe they should hire you to create that list...